# Wrapping a ListView Builder Output with small bubble text boxes that wrap

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to produce a wrapping list of button text boxes. I cannot find a way to wrap this properly. I've included 2 images, one of the current output and another of the desired output.

```
         return Wrap(
                      children: [
                        ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: _filteredHashTags.isEmpty
                                ? hashTagWigetsList.length
                                : _filteredHashTags.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return _buildHashTagList(hashTagWigetsList[index]);
                            }),
```

---

This is what is looks like:
[image]

---

**This is what I'd like it to look like:**

[image]

Comment: is there any specific reason of having `Wrap` and `ListView` at the same time?

Comment: No, I was just playing around trying to wrap it. I need to use listview.builder because of the data I'm loading

Comment: Do you mean buttons in rows and columns wise?

Comment: No, just in a row that wraps

Comment: i think we can avoid using `ListView`, should i share a demo?

Comment: Yes that would be great!

Comment: yes, in listview, items comes after each other. Using for loop, you may return each item as a widget (card, container, or as a button) enclosed in column and row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Demo**

```dart
    final items = List.generate(4, (i) => " item $i"); // response 
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Text("Search Field"),
        ),
        Wrap(
          children: [
            ...items.map(
              (e) => Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(e)),
              ),
            ),

            ///or
            ...List.generate(
              items.length,
              (index) => Text(
                items[index],
                style: TextStyle(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!